# Child items failed to delete when no FK property defined

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, delete-file

I have the following SQL Tables (Removed columns for simplicity):

```
create table dbo.Packs 
(
  Id int identity not null
    constraint Packs_Id_PK primary key clustered (Id)
);
create table dbo.Files
(
  Id int identity not null
    constraint Files_Id_PK primary key clustered (Id),
  PackId int not null
);
alter table dbo.Files
add constraint Files_PackId_FK foreign key (PackId) references dbo.Packs(Id) on delete cascade on update cascade;
```

Then I created the Pocos as follows:

```
public class Pack {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
} // Pack
public class File {
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public int PackId { get; set; } 
  public virtual Pack Pack { get; set; }
} // File
```

And the configuration is:

```
internal class PackMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<Pack> {
  internal PackMapper()
    : base() {

    ToTable("Packs");
    HasKey(x => x.Id);

    Property(x => x.Id).IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
  }
} // PackMapper

internal class FileMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<File> {
  internal FileMapper()
    : base() {

    ToTable("Files");
    HasKey(x => x.Id);

    Property(x => x.Id).IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

    // 1 > CONFIGURATION WITH FK IN ENTITY   
    Property(x => x.PackId).HasColumnName("PackId").IsRequired();
    HasRequired(x => x.Pack).WithMany(x => x.Files).HasForeignKey(x => x.PackId);

    // 2 > CONFIGURATION WITHOUT FK IN ENTITY
    // HasRequired<Pack>(x => x.Pack).WithMany(y => y.Files).Map(z => { z.MapKey("PackId"); });
   }
 } // FileMapper
```

Then I tried to delete a FILE:

```
Pack pack = context.Packs.First(x => x.Id == 31);
 IList<Int32> ids = context.Entry<Pack>(pack).Collection(x => x.Files).Query().Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
foreach (int id in ids) {
  File file = new File() { Id = id };
  context.Files.Attach(file);
  context.Files.Remove(file);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

If I use configuration 1 the files are deleted.

If I use configuration 2 (without the need of a FK property) then I get the error:

> Entities in 'Context.Files' participate in the 'File_Pack' relationship. 0 related 'File_Pack_Target' were found. 1 'File_Pack_Target' is expected.

Why is that? Do I need to specify something else when not defining the FK property?

NOTE: I am using EF 5.

Comment: Hard to believe... What happens if you try to delete only one `file` from a `pack.Files` collection that has more than one element? Does it still delete the `pack` (and all the other `file`s)?

Comment: Maybe I was making some mistake ... I tried to find the problem using EF and SQL queries and I found something wrong ... I just updated my question message and title ... Do you know why do I get this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two ways to define the same relationship - once with a foreign key property and `HasForeignKey` and once without such a property and `MapKey` - change the type of relationship between [*Foreign Key Association and Independent Association*](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/05/foreign-key-vs-independent-associations-in-ef-4/).

With a Foreign Key Association you can specify a relationship by setting a *scalar property*, namely the foreign key property `File.PackId`. This (non-nullable) property always has a value, no matter if you set it explicitly or not. At least it has a default value `0`. With Foreign Key Associations you are not required to set the navigation property `File.Pack` in order to tell EF which `Pack` a `File` refers to. The FK property value is sufficient.

On the other hand when using Independent Associations your model does not have a foreign key property and the only way to tell EF which is the `Pack` related to a particular `File` is setting the navigation property `File.Pack`.

Your relationship is specified as *required* which also means that EF wants to have the navigation property set to an entity and complains about a `null` value. That's what the exception means.

(Don't ask me why it wants to have a related entity when you *remove* the parent entity. I don't know. It shouldn't actually matter when just a SQL `DELETE` statement for the parent has to be issued to the database. But perhaps there is a deeper reason.)

So, in order to make your code working with an Independent Association and get rid of the exception you need to set the navigation property `File.Pack`:

```
Pack pack = context.Packs.First(x => x.Id == 31);
IList<Int32> ids = context.Entry<Pack>(pack).Collection(x => x.Files).Query()
    .Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
foreach (int id in ids) {
    File file = new File() { Id = id, Pack = pack };
    context.Files.Attach(file);
    context.Files.Remove(file);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

**Edit**

BTW: You should be able to use a single database query instead of two queries:

```
IList<Int32> ids = context.Files.Where(f => f.Pack.Id == 31)
    .Select(f => f.Id).ToList();
Pack pack = new Pack { Id = 31 };
foreach (int id in ids) {
    File file = new File { Id = id, Pack = pack };
    context.Files.Attach(file);
    context.Files.Remove(file);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much! Such a small change and such a headache. May I ask you something: Am I using the right approach to delete entities without loading them? I mean, are there other ways besides attach it and then remove it?

Comment: @Shapper: Without loading the entities, it's the right approach. The only alternative is to use direct SQL (which - for performance reasons - I would only use if you have to delete hundreds or thousands of entities).

Comment: @Shapper: There is a little improvement to have only a single database query instead of two queries. See the Edit section in my answer.

Comment: I see. In this case I was loading the Pack first because I need to update its properties. So since I had it I just used it to get the Files ids ... But I will keep your approach in mind for when I am not updating the Pack. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You have a delete cascade in your constraint, that's why it's deleting both entities:

```
add constraint Files_PackId_FK foreign key (PackId) references dbo.Packs(Id) on delete cascade on update cascade;
```

Comment: A delete cascade in SQL does not work that way ... It only deletes the child elements, e.g Files, when the parent element, e.g Pack, is deleted. Not the other way around. So when I delete a File the Pack should not be deleted. But if I delete the Pack then the files associated with it should be deleted.

Comment: The problem I am having is that when I delete a File in EF 5, the Pack is deleted. Am I missing something in the mapping?

Comment: @Shapper: Sorry I didn't read it properly, you are right - Pack is the parent not the child. Have you tried to use the `WillDeleteOnCascade` in your mapping? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679204%28v=vs.103%29.aspx